# I would like to assert response body with JSON file in POSTMAN

Tags: json, iteration, postman, response, postman-collection-runner

I am new to postman and I would like to know how to assert request body from a JSON file which is the same file i pass the values/data in request body in multiple iterations using collection runner.

Would appreciate greatly if someone could help me with this assertion...

enter code here

My JSON input file:

```
[
    {
      "POLCODE":"APOL279906",
      "EnrolmentSegmentValue":"ADF",
      "startDate":"2019-12-01",

   }
]
```

Request Body:

```
[
{
    "code": "{{POLCODE}}",
    "brandCode": " ",
    "lineOfBusinessCode": "HEALTH_INSURANCE",
    "enrolmentSegment": [
        {
            "value": "{{EnrolmentSegmentValue}}",
            "startDate": "{{startDate}}",
            "endDate": ""
        }
    ]
  }   
]
```

Response Body:

```
{
"saleDate": "2019-12-01",
"calculateOnCancellation": false,
"code": "APOL279906",
"brandCode": " ",
"lineOfBusinessCode": "HEALTH_INSURANCE",
"rebateApplicant": [{
    "startDate": "2019-12-01",
    "declarationDate": "2019-12-01"
}],
    "enrolmentSegment": [{
    "flexCodeDefinitionCode": "ENROLMENT_SEGMENTS",
    "startDate": "2019-12-01",
    "value": "ADF"
}]
```

}

Comment: Not clear what do you mean by *assert request body from a JSON file*

Comment: I wanted to verify whether the response body has same values which i have passed from the JSON file. I want to write a test script something like below where i can verify response has the values from iteration data of JSON file.

Example: pm.test("Body contains values", function (req, response) { pm.expect(JSON.stringify(response)).to.include(pm.iterationData)) });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out by exploring POSTMAN Help queries.